# Passing boolean parameter to rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, parameter-passing

I have a post object with a boolean called :published. The the definition for index in the controller looks like this:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @posts }
  end
end
```

And this links to that page:

```
<%= link_to 'All posts', posts_path %>
```

Let's say instead I want the option of showing only posts where post.published? is true.

- Should I have a separate method in the controller to handle the case where only :published posts would be shown?
- Can I alter the index method to handle a parameter being passed to it?
- What would the link_to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep it really simple (no scopes), just do the following

```
def index
  @posts = if params[:published].present?
    Post.where(:published => true)
  else
    Post.all
  end
...
```

And then to add the link with params do

```
%= link_to 'Published Posts', posts_path(:published => true) %>
```

Comment: Thing is if you do it this way, you *need* to specify a value for the parameter, otherwise Rails discards it.

And this is pretty confusing:
`link_to 'Published Posts', posts_path(:published => false)` => will still include published posts

Answer (score 3):

In theory, for filtering results by keywords / categories, it is fine to display the logic in the same controller via a param. I would have it as:

```
<%= link_to 'All posts', posts_path(:published => true) %>
```

Then in your controller / index action:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
  @posts = @posts.where(:published => true) if params[:published].present?
  ...
```

To refactor your code, I would scope the method in the model, with something like:

```
scope :published, where(:published => true)
```

Then in your controller you can just have:

```
@posts = @posts.published if params[:published].present?
```

For more information on chaining / model scopes: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Comment: Thank you for the response. It doesn't give me an error, but it still lists all the posts, not just the published ones.

Comment: You might want to do some debugging on your end. Is the code executing if a param is passed? Are there any `@posts` where published is true? In Rails console, run `Post.where(:published => true)`. Does that return anything?

Comment: Post.where(:published => true) works in console. There are some posts where published is true. I'm not sure how to test if the code is executing. I think that the param may not be getting passed.

Comment: changed to the link to: <%= link_to 'Published Posts', posts_path(:published => :true) %> and that seemed to pass the paramater

Comment: Made the necessary edits on my post. Glad its now working for you

Comment: A nice side effect of using this approach is that you can apply more than one boolean filter without a mess of nested `if`s. For instance: `@posts = Post.all`, then `@posts = @posts.published if params[:published].present?`, then `@posts = @posts.highly_rated if params[:highly_rated].present?`. And it just filters `@posts` successively and independently.